# Powershell - output results one after the other instead of horizontally in a table

Tags: powershell, object

I'm using:

```
Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Select-Object DisplayName,InstallDate
```

Which returns:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030                           20180205           
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.6161                          20161005           
Microsoft Policy Platform                                                               20170927           
Configuration Manager Client                                                            20171019           
Screen Pass 64 v6.6.2                                                                   20170927
```

What is the logic to manipulate the object in order to obtain:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030
20180205

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.6161
20161005
```

Details are:

```
$logiciels = Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Select-Object DisplayName, InstallDate, Usager | out-string
```

That variable is being passed to :

```
$global:infos_finales = @"
DN:$OU2

Lieu: $lieu

Noyau: $noyau - $version_noyau

Rôle: $role

Monté le: $datemontage

Adresse IP: $IPAddress

Adresse MAC: $MACAddress3

Modèle: $modele1 - $modele2

Redémarré le : $BootTimeFinal

__________________________________________________________________

Utilisateur: $user2

Connecté depuis : $temps2
$info_user2

$logiciels


"@
```

That $ infos_finales object containing all the info is being displayed in a richtextbox in a form (all of this is happening in a powershell GUI) with:

```
$richtextbox1.Text = $infos_finales
```

It all works but the formatting is unsuable and ugly, which is why i would prefer it vertically since i don't want to make the textbox suuuper wide to fit all the information.[image]

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER, FINAL SOLUTION USED :**

```
$global:logiciels = Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |
        ForEach-Object {

            if ($_.DisplayName)
            {

                "$($_.DisplayName)"
                "$($_.InstallDate)"
                "$($_.Usager)"
                 ""
            }

        } | out-string
```

Comment: You could use `Format-List`. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: I would say Format-List too but that will add labels. Not sure if the OP wants labels or not.

Comment: I have to wonder why he wants it as list instead of table; if it's to facilitate further parsing, it becomes appropriate to cutpaste my usual lecture on how PowerShell is not bash or batch, and uses a completely different philosophy for the pipe, and think OBJECTS not TEXT for the pipeline.

Comment: That output is being displayed in a RichTextBox in a form, i can't seem to use format-list since it shows  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
 instead of the actual data. I have to use OUT-STRING for the data to show properly in the text box. I'm trying to make it show vertically because the textbox would be very very wide if show in a table.

Comment: You might have explained that in your initial question. ;-)

Comment: In that case, something like this (I forget what RichTextBoxes use for new lines so you may have to tweak that: ***Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | %{"$($_.DisplayName)\r\n$($_.InstallDate"}***

Comment: Guys i apologize for lack of information, check the question again, it's all there.

Comment: You might use a proportional font for that special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to nail it to that format you could use something like this:

```
Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |  
    ForEach-Object {
        If($_.DisplayName -and $_.InstallDate ){
            "$($_.DisplayName)"; "$($_.InstallDate)"; ''
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great option, this is exactly the kind of syntax i had no idea how to approach. Is it possible in that FOREACH to check if the property is not empty? This commands works fine but returns a lot of blank lines when a key doesn't contain these properties.

Comment: Of course. Go ahead and adapt it to your needs!  ;-)

Comment: Haha thanks Olaf! I actually got it working by myself i was about to post it, glad i found the same solution as you. Still a beginner, lots of things to figure out phew

Comment: Final question if you can...in a console it outputs perfectly with new lines between each, but in the textbox, the same variable shows all on one line , any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not working with GUIs. Probably I would have taken a simple `Out-GridView`. You could try to pipe it to a `Out-String`.

Comment: Haha, what a good guess Olaf, Out-String fixes it. Perfection now! Thanks so much